# I can't put spaces in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I try to put spaces in vscode they autodelete themselves, like, I press the space bar, and it puts a space, but immediately deletes it. Please help, I'm super frustrated, it also occurs with tabs.

I've restarted vscode and my computer

Comment: You could try [running it with extensions disabled](/a/63158120/4518341)

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: Are you using hard tabs or soft tabs (i.e. spaces)?

Comment: @wjandrea both of them, tabs for identation, it is an extension, don know which one

Comment: You can run the `Extension Bisect` command to figure out which extension might be causing the issue.